# How to use command line to add SAP CMC licence key

Tags: business-objects

I tried to replace the SAP CMC license key, but after I deleted the old key, I can't open the CMC anymore. IE shows "This page can't be displayed". CMC can't be opened may be because there is no license key in CMC. But I want to add the license key back.

Not sure if I can ask an SAP question on Stack Overflow. But I can't contact SAP support currently. Much appreciated if any one can give me a hint about how to add CMC license by command line or other methods.

Below is the location where I found the license key and deleted it.

[image: CMC license key]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleted or expired license key will disable WACS Server.

There is a [note 2281830](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/2281830) explaining how to add license key via a script:

1. Run command in Bash

   ```
   <InstallDir>/sap_bobj/ccm.sh -anyjs <InstallDir>/sap_bobj/setup/jscripts/addlicensekey.js /CMS <hostname:cmsport> /USERNAME Administrator /PASSWORD <administrator account password> /AUTHENTICATE secEnterprise /License <licensekey>
   ```

   1a. Windows version:

   ```
   <InstallDir>\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win64_x64\addlicensekey.js /CMS <hostname:cmsport> /USERNAME Administrator /PASSWORD <administrator account password> /AUTHENTICATE secEnterprise /License <licensekey>
   ```
2. Restart server

Comment: Thanks for your help. By using the script in windows version, I can add the license key. It didn't give me a success message, but when I run the script again I got below message: Error description: License Key Error: Duplicate Key xxx.  This key has already been installed.   Then I think the key should be added.                                                                                                                 But after I restarted the server and tried to open CMC, it still says 'This page can't be displayed'. You know where I can check the WACS Server status? I use SAP BOE XI 4.0

Comment: here is [another note 2276413](http://service.sap.com/sap/support/notes/2276413) for deleting keys in cmd, delete all keys and add necessary ones again

Comment: [here is](https://help.sap.com/doc/businessobject_product_guides_boexir4_en_xi4sp11_bip_admin_en_pdf/XI4.0.11/en-US/xi4sp11_bip_admin_en.pdf) the adm guide that contains steps how to restart server by scripts, pages 313, 757

Comment: Just found that I can disable/enable WACS Server in CCM without scripts. After enabling it, CMC can be opened again. Thanks again for the detailed information.